# how to print a cursor under specific word in C, like errors/warnings in gcc compiler

Tags: c, formatting, printf

I am trying to print a message and put a cursor under a word or some position of this message, for example:

```
Error : Type incompatibility, line:column 25:6, in a=b;
                                                   ^
```

I've tried to do so using two `printf` function, if we use the same example i gave, it looks like this:

```
printf("Error : Type incompatibility, line:column 25:6, in a=b;");
printf("                                                    ^");
```

note : the spaces in the second `printf` are tabulations.

but when i try it it show the cursor in the begin as it omitted the tabulations.

i replaced the tabulations by typed tabulations (`\t`) and it shift correctly but i have to test every-time the required number of tabulations in function of my string length.

i there any way (a method/a funtion) to do it for any string length without testing every time ?

thanks in advance.

Comment: C has loop statements ...

Comment: Get the length of the first string. Loop printing spaces up to where you want the cursor to be. Print the cursor.

Comment: Don't use tabs if you want reliability; use spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about something like:

```
 void point_cursor(char* error_string, char* expression)
 {
    char* cursor_ptr = strstr(error_string, expression);
    int spaces = cursor_ptr - error_string;

    printf("%s\n", error_string);

    for (int i = 0; i < spaces; i++)
    {
        printf(" ");
    }
    printf("^\n");
 }
```

Then you call it like:

```
char* error = "Error : Type incompatibility, line:column 25:6, in a=b;";
char* expr = "a=b";

point_cursor(error, expr);
```

Output would be:

```
Error : Type incompatibility, line:column 25:6, in a=b;
                                                   ^
```

Comment: very good approach thanks, even the expression may appear in the error_string but i can avoid it; i have just a problem, my expression is a formatted string, even the error_string.
i can use sprintf but i can't predict the error string length when the formatted parameter contains an int, i won't allocate large space to contains the whole expression/error_string, i want to use a generic solution to allocate the exact space to the string to format with sprintf

Comment: Maybe you could use `", in "` as the expression and  a `+5` here? `int spaces = cursor_ptr - error_string + 5;`  ?

Comment: i adopted the solution that print as many space as in the string by calculating its length, but now the printf(" ") seems to omit spaces cause the cursor is at the beginning